# cannot configure qemu 4.1.1 for building

Tags: configuration, qemu, glib, pkg-config

I’m trying to compile Qemu from sources and as such face the well known errors of requiring Glib-2.4 and gthread-2.0

ERROR: glib-2.40 gthread-2.0 is required to compile QEMU

I’m on Linux Mint and I’ve installed libglib-2.0 from the repo

```
AB1@piper11:~$ dpkg -l | grep -i libglib

ii  libglib-object-introspection-perl     0.042-1                           amd64        Perl bindings for gobject-introspection libraries

ii  libglib-perl                          3:1.324-1                         amd64        interface to the GLib and GObject libraries

ii  libglib2.0-0:amd64                    2.50.3-2+deb9u1                   amd64        GLib library of C routines

ii  libglib2.0-0-dbg:amd64                2.50.3-2+deb9u1                   amd64        Debugging symbols for the GLib libraries

ii  libglib2.0-bin                        2.50.3-2+deb9u1                   amd64        Programs for the GLib library

ii  libglib2.0-cil                        2.12.40-2                         amd64        CLI binding for the GLib utility library 2.12

ii  libglib2.0-cil-dev                    2.12.40-2                         amd64        CLI binding for the GLib utility library 2.12

ii  libglib2.0-data                       2.50.3-2+deb9u1                   all          Common files for GLib library

ii  libglib2.0-dev                        2.50.3-2+deb9u1                   amd64        Development files for the GLib library

ii  libglib2.0-doc                        2.50.3-2+deb9u1                   all          Documentation files for the GLib library

ii  libglib2.0-tests                      2.50.3-2+deb9u1                   amd64        GLib library of C routines - installed tests

ii  libglibmm-2.4-1v5:amd64               2.50.0-1                          amd64        C++ wrapper for the GLib toolkit (shared libraries)
```

Here is the content of config.log: https://pastebin.com/6zrSXWAG

I am configuring it for 'arm-softmmu'  as can be seen from the above paste. File `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gthread-2.0.pc` does exist and it's contents are

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: GThread
Description: Thread support for GLib
Requires: glib-2.0
Version: 2.50.3
Libs: -L${libdir} -lgthread-2.0 -pthread
Cflags: -pthread
```

Comment: The config log does not resemble your description or include the errors you mention

Comment: in that case, I do not know what is wrong and why am I getting the error I get. Do you have any other pointers?